# Firestore, when has to change field name during service

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I need to change the String field stored in Firestore to a List

The idea that comes to my mind right now is to transform the list when users enter the first screen if it is not yet transformed into a list. However, if you do this, you have to execute the if conditional statement on the first screen every time.

It would be a very, very slight loss in terms of performance, but I think I am not satisfied somehow. Is there a more effective way?

---

(I put it in MongoDB Tag because thinking that it would be the same in this case)

Comment: Unsure about which database are you using. For Firestore, you'll have to run that logic for sure as in my answer. For Mongo, it seems possible to update field type to array if string without reading the document, checkout this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9x-NqIMnMOv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any direct way in Firestore to update field type so you'll have to first read value of the string field and then update it back in the document. If you need to fetch that document every time user visits the screen maybe you can just check for field type and run this logic.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I use Firestore, Now my head is very complicated. Now that I think about it, even assuming that the app is shut down for a few hours and all field type field names are changed, there is no guarantee that it will be uploaded to the playstore appstore at the same time, and users who use the old version without receiving the new version will get an error unconditionally. It's too complicated problem, don't you know what I can refer to? thank you

Comment: @marsho yes so this can be a bit tricky for Android/iOS apps. It might be a good idea to prompt users to update the application. After releasing the new version, you can update all fields directly in database by a custom script maybe and then drop support previous app version after a few weeks. This won't  be too quick :')